# Property set method not found (expression, audited entity)

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, reflection, expression

I'm running into a `System.ArgumentException` with the message *Property set method not found.* when I try to set a value using reflection with the following statement:

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, newValue, 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance, null, 
            null, null);
```

[This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721673/property-set-method-not-found) indicates that the problem arises because of *inheritance*, however I'm not able to figure out how I could get around it with my current code.

What I'm basically trying to do is setting a **creation date** on a audited entity using **NHibernate**. For this, I got the following set up (*warning, wall of code!*):

#### IEntity

```
public interface IEntity<TKey> : IEquatable<IEntity<TKey>>
{
    TKey Id { get; }
    bool IsTransient { get; }
    TKey GetDefaultId();
}
```

#### EntityBase

```
public abstract class EntityBase<TKey> : IEntity<TKey>
{
    // omitted for brevity
}
```

#### IHasCreationTime

```
public interface IHasCreationTime {
    DateTime CreationTime { get; }
}
```

#### ICreationAudited

```
public interface ICreationAudited : IHasCreationTime {
    string CreatorId { get; }
}
```

#### TestEntity

```
public class TestEntity : EntityBase<int>, ICreationAudited {

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

}
```

#### NHibernateAuditInterceptor

```
internal class NHibernateAuditInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor {

    public override bool OnSave(object entity, object id, object[] state, string[] propertyNames, IType[] types)
    {

        var auditable = entity as ICreationAudited;
        if(auditable == null)
            return false;

        auditable.SetProperty(x => x.CreationTime, DateTime.UtcNow);
        return true;
    }

}
```

#### SetProperty extension

```
public static void SetProperty<T, TProperty>(this T instance, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> selector, TProperty newValue)
    where T: class
{
    var propertyInfo = selector.GetMember() as PropertyInfo;

    propertyInfo.SetValue(instance, newValue, BindingFlags.Public // nonpublic etc..

}
```

#### GetMember extension

```
public static MemberInfo GetMember<T, TProperty>(this Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression)
{

    var memberExp = RemoveUnary(expression.Body);
    return memberExp == null ? null : memberExp.Member;
}
```

#### RemoveUnary extension

```
private static MemberExpression RemoveUnary(Expression toUnwrap)
{
    var unwrap = toUnwrap as UnaryExpression;
    if (unwrap != null)
    {
        return unwrap.Operand as MemberExpression;
    }

    return toUnwrap as MemberExpression;
}
```

What changes could I make to overcome this?

Comment: does this even compile? `var propertyInfo.GetMember() as PropertyInfo;` in your `SetProperty` extension...that's not a proper `c#` assignment expression

Comment: @Leo It compiles and runs well, also the whole SetProperty method works flawlessly except for the case I try to set a property on a derived class.

Comment: mate, I don't know what you are on about here....obviously you don't want help. That line I mentioned above is NOT legal in `C#` and would cause a compilation error. Furthermore, saying it works flawlessly is an absolute lie...specially when you're getting a `System.ArgumentException`...that error is quite straight-forward and the solution as well

Comment: @Leo Whoops, now I see what you mean. That is indeed a typo, can't explain why I didn't see that. I didn't copied it directly from my code, but rewrote it for SO to ommit unnecessary stuff. Care to remove the downvote again?

Comment: sure mate. However, there are still issues in your code, this  `var selector.GetMember() as PropertyInfo;` is still not a valid expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SetProperty` extension method will not compile because of this expression...

```
var selector.GetMember() as PropertyInfo;
```

which is not a valid assignment statement in `C#`. I will assume that you actually meant to say...

```
var propertyInfo = selector.GetMember() as PropertyInfo;
```

If that is the case, the reason why you might be getting an `System.ArgumentException` is because the lambda your passing in has no idea what the actual type is, it only knows about its contract (the interface), however, the reflection method you're using only works with concrete types. To get your `SetProperty` extension method to work you will need to use the actual concrete class as below...

```
public static void SetProperty<T, TProperty>(this T instance, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> selector, TProperty newValue)
   where T : class
    {            
        var propertyInfo = selector.GetMember() as PropertyInfo;
        instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).SetValue(instance, newValue, null);
    }
```

that will work

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and your patience with me. Yes, this is indeed exactly what I wanted, I was just too stupid/tired to proof read my question.